# Filtering values from an array and assigning them in different arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to filter an array given by the user on basis of whether it is positive even, positive odd, negative even, or negative odd.

And, based on this filtration, I am trying to put them in the respected array but my code is working for the 1st part; i.e. it is taking user array but the problem is: ****It is not entering my filtration code.****

The code is here:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

    int main()
{
    int n ;
    cout<<"\n Enter the size of array :-";
    cin>>n;
    int numbers[n];
    int peven[n],podd[n],neven[n],nodd[n];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
        cout<<"\n Enter value "<<i+1<<" = ";
        cin>>numbers[i];
    }
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
    cout<<"  "<<numbers[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\n\n";
    for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
        if (    ((numbers[j]%2) == 0) && (numbers[j] > 0)     ) {
            for(int i = 0; i<1; i--){
                    cin>>peven[i];
                    i++;
                }
            
        }
        else if ( ((numbers[j]%2) == 0) && (numbers[j] < 0) ){
            for(int i = 0; i<1; i--){
                    cin>>neven[i];
                    i++;
                }
        }
        else if ( ((numbers[j]%2) != 0) && (numbers[j] > 0) ){
            for(int i = 0; i<1; i--){
                    cin>>podd[i];
                    i++;
                }
        }
        else {
            for(int i = 0; i<1; i--){
               cin>>nodd[i];
               i++;
            }
        }       
    }
    cout<<"\n The +ve even number array is :- "<<peven[n];
    cout<<"\n The +ve odd number array is :- "<<podd[n];
    cout<<"\n The -ve even number array is :- "<<neven[n];
    cout<<"\n The -ve odd number array is :- "<<nodd[n];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does `for(int i = 0; i<1; i--){` if you look at this `for` loop by itself, make sense to you? You start with `i` being 0, and then as long as it's less than 1 you decrement it. How do you expect to get from 0 to 1 by decrementing this value? And why are you reading anything from `cin`, any more, after you've read all the values in your array?

Comment: Doesn't the for loop works like this 1) It sees initial value 2) It checks the condition 3) It goes inside the loop 4) It comes back and looks for incrementation or decrementation in value of i ????

Comment: @SheikhMuhammedTadeeb Yes, that's correct. But even then, since the for body unconditionally increments `i`, and the incr-step of the for construct unconditionally decrements, `i` will **always** be zero (0) on the eval. I.e. you have an *infinite loop*. The sanity (or lack thereof) of reading values you no longer need to read notwithstanding, that along is a broken algorithm from the outset.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how the for loop works. So, again, how do you expect the for loop to go from 0 to 1 by decrementing it?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, now it's clear where I messed. Thanks for helping : )

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yeah, I got it. I am just a 2nd-year student maybe that's why these mistakes. Anyways thanks for helping : )

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code. Here is a list (which is not exhaustive) :

1. it is forbidden to create a constant size array with an integer which is not constant :

   cin>>n;
   int numbers[n];
2. As Sam Varshavchik mentioned, it is not possible to finish this loop :

   for(int i = 0; i<1; i--)
3. You have no reason to read value from cin after you fill the array to filter. Line like this one should be modified :

   cin>>peven[i];

Here is a correction :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<limits>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    vector<int> peven, podd, neven, nodd;
    int n;

    cout << "Enter the size of vector :-" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> numbers(n, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Enter value " << i + 1 << endl;
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Your vector contains : [";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "  " << numbers[i];
    }
    cout << " ]" << endl; 
    cout << endl;

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (((numbers[j] % 2) == 0) && (numbers[j] >= 0)) {
            peven.push_back(numbers[j]);
        }
        else if (((numbers[j] % 2) == 0) && (numbers[j] < 0)) {
            neven.push_back(numbers[j]);
        }
        else if (((numbers[j] % 2) != 0) && (numbers[j] >= 0)) {
            podd.push_back(numbers[j]);
        }
        else {
            nodd.push_back(numbers[j]);
        }
    }
    cout << "\n The +ve even number array is : [";
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)peven.size(); j++) {
        cout << " " << peven[j];
    }
    cout << "] " << endl;
    cout << "\n The +ve odd number array is : [";
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)podd.size(); j++) {
        cout << " " << podd[j];
    }
    cout << "] " << endl;
    cout << "\n The -ve even number array is : [";
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)neven.size(); j++) {
        cout << " " << neven[j];
    }
    cout << "] " << endl;
    cout << "\n The -ve odd number array is : [";
    for (int j = 0; j < (int)nodd.size(); j++) {
        cout << " " << nodd[j];
    }
    cout << "] " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I really appreciate your effort. Thanks again for helping comrade   : )

Comment: @SheikhMuhammedTadeeb please take time to validate my answer !